# How do I replace single quotes with double quotes in a python array without replacing the single quotes in the json values?

Tags: python, json, api, rest, python-requests

I have an array called `managable`:

```py
r = requests.get("https://discord.com/api/v8/users/@me/guilds", headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
})

guilds = r.json()
managable = []

for guild in guilds:
    if int(guild["permissions"]) & 32 != 0:
        managable.append(guild)
```

where I replace some boolean values in it:

```py
strmanagable = str(managable).replace("True", '"true"').replace("False", '"false"').replace("None", '"none"')
```

and it returns an array like this:

```json
[{'id': '0', 'name': '\'something\''}, {'id': '1', 'name': '\'two\''}]
```

I would like to replace the single quotes with double quotes in the array above, without replacing the single quotes in the json values.
I tried using the replace function (`strmanagable.replace("'", "\"")`), but it replaces single quotes in the json values too, which I don't want.

Comment: Just convert `managable` to JSON, True -> true conversion will be done automatically.

Comment: hi @snakecharmerb It seems OP would like to recognise your contribution... would you post an answer here as well? (so that I can upvote you also!)

Answer (score 0):

Are you look for this function `json.dumps()`? It converts the list into a string literal, then `True` becomes 'true' automatically

```
import json

lis1 = [{'id': '0', 'name': True}, {'id': '1', 'name': False}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'two'}]
lis1 = json.dumps(lis1)
```

Output

```
'[{"id": "0", "name": true}, {"id": "1", "name": false}, {"id": "2", "name": "two"}]'
```

Then if you need to convert it back, do this

```
lis2 = json.loads(lis1)
print(lis2)

[{'id': '0', 'name': True},
 {'id': '1', 'name': False},
 {'id': '2', 'name': 'two'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

@snakecharmerb solved my question, I just had to convert `managable` to json

Comment: but technically I have showed you the code to do it